# Form Component submit form in angular 12

Tags: angular, angular12

I create one user registration form and want submit this form, but I stuck here, my validation it's not work in submit form, also show my code,

This is Form submitting with validation, it's basic validation,

**formcompoenet.componenet.html**

```
<h3>Angular Form Component</h3>
<div class="container">
    <h1>User Registration</h1>
    <form #login="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(login)">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label><br/>
            <input #firstname="ngModel" required minlength="2" maxlength="7" type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" ngModel>
            <div *ngIf = "firstname.invalid && (firstname.dirty || firstname.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
               ghhg
                
                <div *ngIf = "firstname.errors.required">First name Required</div>
<!--                <p *ngIf="firstname.errors.minlength">Firs name should be 2 char</p>
                <p *ngIf="firstname.errors.maxlength">Firs name should be 12 char</p>-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <pre></pre>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label><br/>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" ngModel>
        </div>
        <pre></pre>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email ID</label><br/>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ngModel>
        </div>
        <pre></pre>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Password</label><br/>
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" ngModel>
        </div>
        <pre></pre>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**formcompoenet.compoenent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-formcomponenet',
    templateUrl: './formcomponenet.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./formcomponenet.component.css']
})
export class FormcomponenetComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
    
    submit(login:any) {
        console.log("Fome Submit Successfull", login);
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
$ ng serve
√ Browser application bundle generation complete.                                                                                                                                                                        

Initial Chunk Files   | Names         |      Size                                                                                                                                                                        
vendor.js             | vendor        |   2.67 MB                                                                                                                                                                        
polyfills.js          | polyfills     | 508.81 kB                                                                                                                                                                        
styles.css, styles.js | styles        | 381.00 kB                                                                                                                                                                        
Error: src/app/formcomponenet/formcomponenet.component.html:11:48 - error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
11                 <div *ngIf = "firstname.errors.required">First name Required</div>                                                                                                                                    
                                                  ~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  src/app/formcomponenet/formcomponenet.component.ts:5:18                                                                                                                                                                
    5     templateUrl: './formcomponenet.component.html',                                                                                                                                                                
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                 
    Error occurs in the template of component FormcomponenetComponent.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this :

```
<div *ngIf = "login.controls.firstname.errors">First name Required</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

as the error says the `firstname.errors` can be `null` and break the application, you need to include the `?` (called  the safe navigation operator) like this:

```
<div *ngIf = "firstname.errors?.required">First name Required</div>
```

Comment: Thank You, for solve my solution, but i search every where, finally solve than you